# Casting to ElementHost not possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, user-controls, elementhost

I have an VSTO Outlook Add-in (a kind of winforms app) and I am using an Outlook control that allows embedding a custom winforms user control.

Instead I want to embed an WPF user control so I create a Winforms user control and place within it an ElementHost. Finally I embed the WPF user control within the ElementHost.

So the structure is:

```
  VSTO Outlook Add-in <---> Outlook Control <---> Winforms User Control <----> ElementHost <----> WPF user control
```

Now from my WPF user control, from its code-behind (*.xaml.cs) I am trying to access a method hosted in the winforms user control so I do below:

```
ElementHost eh = (ElementHost) this.Parent; <----- error
MyWinformUserControl winformUC = eh.Parent;
winformUC.MyMethod();
```

When trying to cast to ElementHost I get a compilation error that says:

```
CS0030: Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost'
```

If I change to:

```
ElementHost eh = this.Parent as ElementHost;
```

then compiler says:

```
CS0039: Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion.
```

So how can I cast into an ElementHost?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @EpicKip See my post. I have updated it with the compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a MyWinFormsControl which has a DoSomething method, you can call it from WPF like this:

```
public partial class MyWPFControl : UserControl
{
    public MyWPFControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var hwnd = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
        var host = System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromChildHandle(hwnd.Handle) as ElementHost;
        var myUC = host.Parent as MyWinFormsControl;
        myUC.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

However, I'd suggest you revert the dependency and pass whatever you need to the WPF control. It could be passing the whole control, could be passing a delegate, or could be raising an event in the WPF control and handling in WinForms control.

```
public partial class MyWPFControl : UserControl
{
    public MyWPFControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public MyWinFormsControl Control { get; set; }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Control.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

And here is MyWinFormsControl

```
public partial class MyWinFormsControl : UserControl
{
    public MyWinFormsControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ((MyWPFControl)elementHost1.Child).Control = this;
    }
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course all need some null checking.

Comment: Yeap, this is what i ended up doing, reverting the dependency and passing the winforms user control to the WPF user control, in fact, I "inyected" the winforms user control into the WPF user control constructor and then in the WPF user control I set a property as you said. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! That's the right way of doing it :)